# how to efficiently monitor system stat using vmstat?

Tags: linux, monitoring, administration

Am getting the real-time memory stats from **vmstat** command. I did this using following steps:

```
$nohup vmstat 60 > vmstatrecord.app &
```

the command executes in background and writes the log to the file **vmstatrecord.app**. When i see use the command

```
$ps -A | grep stat
```

I could see the vmstat running in the background and i could also access the log using tail command as:

```
$tail -f vmstatrecord.app
```

the file updates every 60sec interval.

Now my question is 
1. **process continues to write to the file** so what will happen if i leave for days ?

Assumption:
If the process writes the file forever **am afraid that the file size might grow too large**

1. If my assumption is correct and my steps are inefficient. Is there any alternatives to achieve what am trying to achieve from my above steps ?

Answer (score 1):

This question should better be asked on superuser.com or maybe serverfault.com, as it's not about programming.

Yes, your file will keep growing. That's what the 2nd parameter of vmstat is for - run `vmstat 60 1440` to stop after a day (note 1440 = 60 minutes * 24 hours). Once when i had this problem, i made a crontab entry:

```
0 0 * * * vmstat 60 1440  > /some/where/vmstat.out
```

to restart the output every day.

Comment: so u r suggesting me to restart or schedule the job ? by cron